# Ruby worker fails randomly with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We use Amazon PubSub for messaging between Rails services and this runs as a worker on Heroku alongside the associated service. Right now the code is polling for PubSub messages and the causes the processing of a message to occur. I'm seeing a 1-3% error rate where the code throws a NoMethodError when accessing an instance method a model in three different instances. I'll show one here.

First the model:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal, touch: true
  belongs_to :retailer
  ...
end
```

Then the failing code:

```
def location_update(stores, new_locations)
  stores.each do |store|
    deal_id = store.deal ? store.deal.id.to_s : "(no deal exists)"
    ...
  end
end
```

The error is:

Nov 7 18:25:56 d.db858851-921e-4233-ae7c-8d3f8e03bca1 app[worker.1] undefined method 'deal' for #< Store:0x007ffb78435000>

It is failing on `store.deal`. Clearly, this is a Store object and deal exists on Store, as can be seen in the model and by the fractional failure rate (97-99% succeed and all execute this code).

It is behaving as if the Store class is not loaded. Does the code need to do something to ensure the class is loaded? If so, why does it only fail 1-3% of the time?

(Ruby 2.3.1, Rails 4.2.7)

Comment: This sounds like a problem with a single worker not picking up code changes (perhaps not restarting when it should) -- not a problem with anything in the code. Are you running multiple workers and can you see how long they've been running? Have you tried restarting them?

Comment: Heroku restarts once a day and on every deploy.